# UIDeviceOrientation ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have the following code to fill a view according to the orientation. This always returns landscape.

```
- (void)setData:(BCPlaylist *)list  {
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
      NSLog(@"portrait");
      [self setPlaylist:list];
      [self renderPlaylist];
      [activity stopAnimating];
    }else{
      NSLog(@"landscape");
      [self setPlaylist:list];
      [self renderPlaylistOne];
      [activity stopAnimating];
     }
}
```

I change views correctly in `- (void)animateRotation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
               duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {`
But that doesn't work when already in landscape or portrait when changing a playlist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] for checking orientation use statusbar orientation to get the exact orientation.

```
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

Comment: I submitted en edit to correct `orientation` type from `UIDeviceOrientation` to `UIInterfaceOrientation`.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a warning, use :

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd always get landscape, because that's your default (from your if statement). If you walk through the debugger with a breakpoint there, you'll see that the orientation reported is that of *Unknown*.

In fact, your code is fine, but this is a limitation of the simulator. If you take the same code, using *Device* orientation and not *Interface* orientation, you'll get actual values if you use it on the physical device, which can be driven by the if-statement you have.